# Serialized data not always outputting to a file

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a series of classes that gather data from an internal SQLite database. A typical one looks like this

```
public class foo
{
    [AutoIncrement, XmlIgnore, PrimaryKey]
    public int tid {get; private set;}

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string barID {get;set;}

    public string someData {get;set;}

    [Ignore]
    public List<bar> Bar {private set{}; get {return myApp.Singleton.DBManager.GetListOfObjects<bar>("id", barID); }}
}

public class bar
{
     [AutoIncrement, PrimaryKey, XmlIgnore]
     public int tid {get;private set;}

     public string id {get;set;}

     [XmlIgnore]
     public string barTwoID {get;set;}

     public bool isSet {get;set;}

     [Ignore]
     public barTwo BarTwo {private set{}; get {return myApp.Singleton.DBManager.GetSingleObject<barTwo>("id", barTwoID);}}
 }
```

(you get the idea)

I fill the classes during the app and before saving to a file, all of the data appears when I look at foo in the debugger (by that I mean, bar and barTwo are correctly populated).

I pass foo to my serialiser, but when I examine the output file, there is no guarantee that all of the data that I saw earlier is in the outputted file.

My serialiser looks like this

```
static BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public static void CreateSchema<T>(T schema, string id, string type, bool dump = false) where T:IDatabase, new()
    {
        try
        {
            bgWorker.DoWork += async (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) =>
            {
                var emptyNs = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
                var filename = Path.Combine(TechApp2.Singleton.ContentDirectory, 
                                       string.Format("{0}-{1}.xml", typeof(job).ToString(), id));
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, schema, emptyNs);

                await Torrent.CopyAndMove(filename, dump);
                await SendEmail.SendEmailOut(filename, type, id);
            };
            bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown - {0}:{1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

`T schema` (in this case) is foo - it is designed to take just about anything though.

From what I've read, the `private set{}` on the likes of `List<bar> Bar{...}` is required to get the serialiser to show those linked classes in the serialised output. I've also read this works, but is not always the best way to do it, but with very little every explained on how to make it more robust.

Any advice on this would be appreciated as it's driving me around the bend on why sometimes everything is there (in the file) and sometimes it's not.

Adding `[Serializable]` before the class doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: As with toilets, you should always `.Flush()` after you are done with a file.

Comment: @Aron that's a common belief, closing the file is enough, though. Requiring flush would be horrible API design.

Comment: The issue isn't really the file itself, more the serialisation of the classes into the file. Also given the file is created within the using construct, that should close and then remove the object for the GC to do it's bidding